# Error implementing Vimeo-networking

Tags: java, android, vimeo-android

I have tried many different ways of getting Vimeo networking into my app, but nothing has worked. If I remove the implementation it works just fine so I know this is the issue.
`compile 'com.vimeo.networking:vimeo-networking:1.1.1'`

gives me this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   > java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

I have searched all over and have yet to find a solution (yes I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project)

Comment: Ok will do. I have to wait till tomorrow, but I added the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION: anthonycr's answer was perfect, but I also had to do this:

```
implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version") {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
}

implementation ('com.vimeo.networking:vimeo-networking:1.1.1') {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the result of the `vimeo-networking` library including a dependency which you are also separately including in your gradle file. [Looking at the gradle file for a hint](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/blob/v1.1.1-release/vimeo-networking/build.gradle), a prime suspect is the intellij annotations jar `'com.intellij:annotations:12.0@jar'` dependency, which I have seen cause similar problems when also included in your main project as well as a sub-projects.

The solution to this is to exclude the annotations jar when compiling in the `vimeo-networking` library as follows:

```
compile ('com.vimeo.networking:vimeo-networking:1.1.1') {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
}
```

Try this and see if it fixes your build exception. Generally I've seen that the cause for the `Unable to merge dex` error is that there are multiple definitions of the same class in the final dex file, usually resulting from the inclusion of a jar file multiple times.

Comment: I think you are right because my error was saying something about a duplicate, but it didn't work.

Comment: It says Multiple dex files define Lorg/intellij/lang/annotations/JdkConstants$TreeSelectionMode; in the gradle console. Is there something else I might need to do?

Comment: Thank you! I am new to Android and your response lead me to the solution. Thanks.